# Able to Upload Binary to iTunes Connect from China?

Tags: iphone, xcode, tcp, app-store-connect, firewall

I'm located in China, and in the past, I have uploaded binary to iTunes Connect several times with no problem. I recently upgraded to Lion and XCode 4.3, and have been unable to succesfully upload. After validating my binary (using Archive, always works fine), I press Distribute, and after several minutes, I get the following errors. I contacted Developer Support, who told me there was nothing they could do, as my problem is due to being located in China.

I have a hard time believing that because CanYouSeeMe.org shows my port 443 as open, and so my question is: Is anyone on SO located in China and do you have problems uploading binary? If so, what steps do you take to make it work?

---

My Error Codes:

> Communication Error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity. You need to have outbound access to TCP Port 443.
>
> An exception has occurred:Operation timed out.
>
> Could not connect to Apple's web service.
>
> An error occurred while connecting to the transport host https://itmsdav.apple.com: Operation timed out.
>
> Could not start delivery: all transports failed diagnostics.

Comment: Has your router configuration changed at all?

Comment: Never touched the router, but to be sure, I have attempted this with 3 different internet connections.

Comment: If possible, and of course depending on your data plan/size of app... can you try via a 3G phone network?

Comment: I will have to give that a shot next. Now, to find a access to a 3G network.... (I only own an iTouch).

Comment: Well, here's the latest. I had a friend upload some binary from his computer, his certificates, his app, but using my wifi network. Everything went fine. This appears to be an issue either with my version of Lion, XCode, or Application Loader. I will update this thread on resolution of my problem or further developments to help those in the future who search for the error messages I wrote in my post.

Comment: Success! After uninstalling XCode and reinstalling, success. FYI, this was without using my VPN on a Chinese internet connection. Thank you all for the suggestions.

Comment: Happen same thing to me Ben. I tried all possible solutions. I use fastlane, but at the low level it's the same case as yours. Only way to be able to successfully upload is to turn off proxy or vpn.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on to the answer, if this screenshot is what you getting.
(My case is from XCode 4.5.2 Organizer during Distribute...

[image: Error Screen while upload, exception occurred itmsdav.apple.com]

You should try another internet connection, in my case it failed during WIFI but SUCCEEDED when I use Tethering!

This is not a permanent solution to original question but as least app is submitted now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your ISP or router has some wall up blocking all outbound traffic. I'm no expert on china but I think that you should be able to tether your phone. If you can't, try a random Wi-Fi hotspot at one of the big stores. (In the U.S. Starbucks)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I have tried at many different wifi hotspots. Also, at my home, I was able to do upload binary before upgrading to Lion and XCode 4.3. I will try tethering, though I will have to find an available phone (I do my testing on an iTouch).

Comment: TheDeveloper, it asks for login, then does nothing. Please see above comment thread for the latest.

Comment: It does the same for me. In xcode set the build for iOS device and in the tab Product click Archive. Once it's done it will open a window with your app icon, to the right there are 3 button, click submit and sign into you iTunesConnect account. Did it work?

Comment: I think you are describing XCode 4.2. As I stated in my question,  I am using Xcode 4.3, (which for me only shows the Validate and Distribute button) and I have done that process. The error code shows up at the end of that process, several minutes after pressing distribute (through AppStore).

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Application loader old version like 2.5.2.
```